# Flutter how to embed date picker

Tags: flutter, datepicker

I have seen lot of examples in flutter on how to display date picker as a pop up dialog and pick a date.

What I want to do is to display the date picker permanently on the page.

I found following code to display  CupertinoDatePicker. But is there a way to display material date picker similarly?

```
Container(
          height: 200,
          child: CupertinoDatePicker(
            mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
            initialDateTime: DateTime(1969, 1, 1),
            onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {
              // Do something
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: `CalendarDatePicker` ?

Comment: Yes i can embed inside. Is there a way to customize it?

Comment: you have some optional params in the constructor

Comment: I want to customize thins like color, is there a way to do it?

Comment: check the sources https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ce40de69b7/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/pickers/calendar_date_picker.dart#L374 and type `ctrl-F color`